# Given a date I want to find the last date that is not a weekend and does not exist in a list of other dates

Tags: date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dateadd

I have a table MY_TABLE that has a column ALL_DATES whose values are just a bunch of dates

I am trying to write a UDF where given a date, I want to return the previous date that is not a weekend and does not exist in ALL_DATES from my table. If either of these conditions is not met I would like to continue getting the date before that until both conditions are met (not a weekend and not in the list of dates)

So far for my function I have

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_PREVIOUS_DATE(_CURRENT_DATE VARCHAR)
RETURNS DATE
$$
SELECT DATEADD(day, -1, _CURRENT_DATE) AS PREVIOUS_DATE
$$;
```

I know I can check if it exists in the list of dates by doing

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_PREVIOUS_DATE(_CURRENT_DATE VARCHAR)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN
$$
SELECT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM MY_TABLE
  WHERE ALL_DATES = _CURRENT_DATE
)
$$;
```

But I'm not sure how to combine these two sqls along with checking the day of the week of PREVIOUS_DATE to return the last date that satisfies my conditions

Comment: You would need to loop inside the function to get a date, check it against the table and whether it is a weekend until you get to a date that is satisfied, and then return that date.  Have you checked the documentation on how to do a loop in python, javascript, or Snowflake scripting?

Answer (score 0):

We can use snowflake Snowscript to achieve this. Only difference is it will be using a stored procedure.

IF requirement is compulsory for function you can go with Python or Javascript UDF.

```
create or replace procedure GetPrevDate(cd date)
returns variant
language sql
execute as caller
as 
BEGIN

    LOOP
        if (not exists(select 1 from alldates where dt = :cd) 
            and dayofweek(:cd) <> 0 
            and dayofweek(:cd) <> 6)
        then 
            return :cd;
        else
            cd := dateadd('day',-1,:cd);
        end if;
    end LOOP;
    
    END;
        
call GetPrevDate('2023-07-21');
```